# Updating a column in sql database

Tags: sql, magento

I imported a newsletter list in Magento from Magentogo. However, all of them show as "Unsubscribed" how do I modify the column? I need to change subscriber_status to 1 which is activated from 2.

Comment: Something like "update YourTable set subscriber_status =1 where subscriber_status = 2"

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple `UPDATE` query.

Your query should be something like:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET column1 = 'some value'
WHERE column1 = 'another value'
```

Please go through this tutorial to learn more: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/